# How to debug my own DLL file that is imported to other application as a plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, visual-studio-debugging

We created a C# project in Visual Studio, That results a DLL file. If we import that DLL file to 3rd party application it acts as a plugin. Everything is fine. But there is a bug in my DLL file which I can find it by placing a debug point. But I don't know how can I do that for DLL which is imported to 3rd party application.

Comment: Are you able to use the visual studio remote debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might or might not work, but you can [attach to a running process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Grimace. Where were you these days ;). I been struggling since last week.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the Debug tab in Project Properties, set the Start Action to Launch External Process, then select the 3rd-party EXE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

- `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write()` may cover your case, if the 3rd party application is being run in Debug mode - you'll see the content at the Output window.
- You may detect if your component is running under Visual Studio, even when hosted by another application, by checking `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`. If that's the case, you may dump debug information to a local file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement some unit tests in your project to narrow down the problem.